# Kingsman vs King's man

Tags: meaning, etymology, compounds, neologisms

When you look up the word **kingsman** in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kingsman#English), its etymology shows that it is compounded with **king** + **s** + **man** in the same way as Klansman (Ku Klux Klan's member), huntsman (a man who hunts) or kinsman (a man who is one of a person's blood relations).

I believe that such nouns have evolved into their current forms as **' (apostrophe)** was not absolutely necessary.

I thought about the difference in their nuance and meaning between **kingsman** and **king's man** especially after watching the movie [**Kingsman: The Secret Service**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingsman:_The_Secret_Service).

The meaning of **kingsman** is not even listed in Oxford Online Dictionary, Collins and Merriam-Webster and only Wiktionary has the following meaning:

> (military) The **lowest enlisted rank** in the [Duke of Lancaster's
>   Regiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duke_of_Lancaster%27s_Regiment) of the British Army, equivalent to private in the rest of the
>   British Army.

The Duke of Lancaster's Regiment doesn't seem to be well known (at least to me) and there must be a reason why the word **kingsman** is not even listed in a major dictionary.

1. What does **kingsman** mean exactly? If it means the **lowest enlisted rank** like **private** in the U.S. army, it doesn't sound very prestigious and honorable.
2. Is it a kind of neologism that suddenly became very popular when the movie was released? I am particularly interested in finding out how this word had been used in BrE and AmE before the movie was released.
3. What is the difference in terms of nuance and meaning between kingsman and king's man?

Comment: People are lazy or stupid. For this type of shortening: Lazy. That is the simple reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia informs us that the Duke of Lancaster's Regiment was formed in 2004 from three regiments, one of which was the ***King's*** *Regiment*, which itself was formed in 1958 from two regiments, one of which was the ***King's*** *Regiment, Liverpool*, one of oldest infantry units in the British Army, formed in 1685..  So it's no surprise that its members became known as *kingsman* or that the regiment adopted the nickname for its lowest ranked NCO.  The nickname *kingsman* is attested to by Partridge's *Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*.  I expect that it would be the membership that was prestigious, regardless of rank.

Partridge notes that the nickname *King's Men* belongs to the 78th Regiment of Foot, formed in 1793, later (1881) the Seaforth Highlanders, a derivation not from their name but from their Gaelic motto *Cuidich 'n Righ*, help the king.

The *OED* (you'll have to check the paper supplement) does not distinguish between *kingsman* and *King's man*, and lists only non-military usages:

- The King's Majesty's Servants, a dramatic company under James I (from 1613)
- A Loyalist in the American Revolution (from 1809, which seems a little late since the Treaty of Paris was signed in 1783 ending a brouhaha that started in 1765)
- A member of King's College, Cambridge (from 1803, which seems more than a little late since the college was founded in 1441)

All of the above showing both the attributive and possessive forms derived from a royal association.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes sense why it was used for the movie title.

Answer (score 0):

A kingsman was also neckerchief worn by costermongers.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costermonger):

> Costermongers had their own dress code. In the mid nineteenth century,
>   men wore long waistcoats of sandy coloured corduroy with buttons of
>   brass or shiny mother of pearl. Trousers, also made of corduroy, had
>   the distinctive bell-bottomed leg. Footwear was often decorated with a
>   motif of roses, hearts and thistles. Neckerchiefs — called king's men
>   — were of green silk or red and blue.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. We are looking for longer answers that include references and citations. If you need assistance in framing an answer, please visit our [Help Page on "How to write an answer"](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

King's Men was the name of Shakespeare's theatre company after it received its royal patent from James I in 1603. Anything after that is, as with many things, simply a derivation from what Shakespeare did.